# Getting the image from the phpmyadmin mysql.

Tags: php, phpmyadmin

I have a table as data in that i have only a image as blob data type and no image name.when i upload the image it is getting upload and at blob it is showing the size of the image .but when i am retriving the image it is not showing the image instead showing the empty image shape.how can i rectify it.

```
<html>
</body>
<form action=retrive.php method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
id<input type=text name=id>
<input type=submit name=submit1>
<img src=retrive.php?id='id'>
</form>
</body>
</html>

    retrive.php
    <?php
    $con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","biiling_detalis"); 
    if(mysqli_connect_errno())
    {
    die("mysql connection is failure.".mysqli_connect_error());
    }
    echo "connected successfully";
    $value1=mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$_GET['id']);
    $query=mysqli_query($con,"select * from image WHERE id='$value1';");
    $row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($query);
    $image=$row['image'];
    header("Content-type: image/jpg");//when the slash is changed to \ it shows the name of the image.
    echo $image;

    ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

As Johannes suggested, the "connected successfully" message would lead to printing of the bits that don't represent an image.

Secondly, what is the reason for storing the images in mysql? Wouldn't it be better to store the image as a file and have the link to it stored in the db? This way if your app scales you can put the static files folder in a cdn. Also, I'd think it would be faster to serve static files directly rather than serve it via mysql programmatically this way.

Comment: You are correct about your speed assumptions. It's complex of course as it heavily depends on the software and hardware used, but servering static files and querying the database for small data is usually faster than querying the database for huge blob data. Blob should not commonly be used in web applications where static files are available as alternative.

Answer (score 0):

I bet you have error_reporting off and didn't check your logfiles either. You can't send any headers after you sent output already. So the content type header will not be send, as you output "connected successfully" before that.

Plus, the "connected successfully" text in your output will make the image invalid anyway.

Solution: fix the PHP code.

Other possible improvements:
- check if ID is even valid
- fetch only the image column instead of * for better performance
- include "limit 1" in your query for better performance

Answer (score 0):

```
<img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,<?php echo base64_encode($image); ?>" />
```

Comment: That doesn't actually output the image but an (invalid because not complete) HTML page with an embedded image. You're also using XHTML syntax (self-closing img tag) without sending the proper content-type.